# Sink that Bismark! (Errr, pig)

Tags: code-golf

Pig-latin is a made-up language that is translated into by moving the first letter of a word to the end and adding `ay` to the end. For example: `hello` translates into pig-latin as `ellohay`. Therefore, translating pig-latin back into English is dropping the `ay` at the end and moving the last letter to the start (like `oodbyegay` to `goodbye`). When writing it out, some people will put a `-` at the end before moving the first letter for clarity, so it reads (for example) `ello-hay` instead of `ellohay` for `hello`. We will use this hyphenated version for this challenge.

## Objective

Undo a pig-latin string.

## Instructions

Write a program/function that takes one argument, a *single* word in the form of a string. If that word is in pig-latin, the program/function must output (i.e. `return` or print it) the non-pig-latin word. If it isn't pig-latin, output the word as-is.

Pig-latin for this challenge will be in the following format:

```
ello-hay
```

If the word ends in `-*ay`, it is pig-latin, where the `*` is a single wildcard character.

Non-letter characters should be treated as a normal letter. For multiple dashes, ignore all except the last.

## Examples

Using fictitious `unpig()` Python function for demo.

```
unpig("ello-hay")    #=> hello
unpig("hello-world") #=> hello-world
unpig("hello")       #=> hello
unpig("pple-aay")    #=> apple
unpig("apple")       #=> apple
unpig("ig-Stay")     #=> ig-Stay (+1 to ETHproductions for noticing.)
unpig("ello----hay") #=> hello---
unpig("la$s-gay")    #=> gla$s
unpig("ig-pay-yay")  #=> yig-pay
```

## Rules

1. Standard loopholes apply
2. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.
3. Built-in functions (specifically for this purpose) are not permitted.
4. Use header `# Language, XX bytes`

## Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=127963,OVERRIDE_USER=46066;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```js
s=>s.replace(/(.*)-(.)ay$/,'$2$1')
```

#### Test cases

```js
let unpig =

s=>s.replace(/(.*)-(.)ay$/,'$2$1')

console.log(unpig("ello-hay"))    // => hello
console.log(unpig("hello-world")) // => hello-world
console.log(unpig("hello"))       // => hello
console.log(unpig("pple-aay"))    // => apple
console.log(unpig("apple"))       // => apple
console.log(unpig("ig-Stay"))     // => ig-Stay
```

Comment: Is this a function? I don't do JS (ES6).

Comment: I literally had the exact same solution, except using double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: Nvm. Great start!

Comment: @juniorRubyist Its an anonymous function that can be assigned to any variable(in this case 'unpig').

Comment: Seems pretty unbeatable.

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 61 bytes

```php
function f($v){echo preg_replace("#(.*)-(.)ay$#","$2$1",$v);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCoMwEEDRvaeQcRZJMYJuY/EoZRhGI0gyBC2I9Nhdp3b/39egZZw0aIWUl/gE1U0c0Qm@zEfkfU2xng2@7SUcUq1ZllcW3YjFQGO6h3Wms3RiAy3ggD20d@w/5Ub/o/XlG5Nj4iA/)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 46 bytes

without a function

```php
<?=preg_replace("#(.*)-(.)ay$#","$2$1",$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxCoAgEADQ3c84HTRUqNXMT4lDDh3EDrc@vNmi@fG48twTVxYKR@kRmBs5xBuCSMdHkQeVcxA3zKRBar8Yp73BW0mwoDa1gv2vCXM@/XIZc6UX)

Comment: Must be a function. Invalid.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline fixed

Comment: Actually, 22 minutes ago, your 46 byte solution became valid.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to xnor.*

These are anonymous lambda functions that can be assigned to, say `unpig`.

```python
lambda s:[s,s[-3]+s[:-4]][s[-4]+s[-2:]=="-ay"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BCsIwEETv/YpQhCp2L7WnQL/CYwyy2tgGYhKaiOTrYxop0bm92dlh1wY/G93Fl7ZyGi5R4fM2InGUudYxOPGjYxR6zlmifiXoKB@GGjDUPHrh/PWOTjgyEFaRpEYoZWDG0LRfnrPxNosa/6wNrFUCsORxNTaQE5x9meWqpJ96hTsHU@G0YTFASE7Fq@phFiKJ1KScSnPQLlJ7kv/ey0P8AA)

### Regex solution, 49 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub('(.*)-(.)ay',r'\2\1',s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BCoMwEEX3OcXskhQj1KXgKbqspcSa6kBMwiRSPH2qFpHO7r35w/DDkkbvqjy7gEPTZqunrtcQazJlnDvBRXmRSpRSL7wg3lbtlRdRMpyCpwRkcjIxPV86mggN3Bmsw421Xo3byY/HXXw82f5PHRCCNUqfeb2JA3BQt7Tu2IOxtydAQAfn13pPBUKXYG8hUOYv)

Comment: You don't need to use `and/or` when short-circuiting isn't required. Selecting from a list works and is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7, <s>68</s> <s>55</s> 52 bytes

```python
def up(s):print(s,s[-3]+s[:-4])[s[-4]+s[-2:]=="-ay"]
```

Uses a ternary-like operator.

-13 bytes thanks to officialaimm and an update in rules.

-3 Changed ternary operator. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/470376/3210045.

Comment: `s[0:len(s)-4]` can be replaced by just `s[:-4]`. And few spaces can be avoided by squeezing `]if` and `"else`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
D'-¡θ¦„ayQi¨¨Á¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f8wNWFiMWX//0QnLcKhwq7DqMKm4oCeYXlRacKowqjDgcKo//9pZy1wYXkteWF5)

`θ` is replaced by `®è` on TIO since it hasn't been pulled there yet.

Comment: Best golfing! You win.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 29 bytes

```bash
p:
([]+)$1 \- []$2 ay=>$2 $1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>59</s> 60 bytes

- 1 byte added thanks to @Erik the Outgolfer: $ to ensure `ig-payyay` outputs the same and not `yig-pa`

```python
lambda a:a[-3]+a[:-4]if re.search("-.ay$",a)else a
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcyxDoIwEMbxnadoGgeIHgtOJD4JMpxw0ialvZQa0wd3roA6YPTW3/0/jkE5W6WbZT2czsngeOlRYI0NVO0emxqOrb4KT@VE6DuVSygx7uQBCzITCcz0yM6H@SOx1zbk61QuyRgHCqMsCjFftkG16t150y/@A9/Zd8hsCPCzujVc8E@nB2CM8RWmh3XQYafoCQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Just the same RegEx replacement as everyone else, first posted by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127964/58974).

```
r"(.*)-(.)ay$"ÏiZ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ciIoLiopLSguKWF5JCLPaVo&input=ImlnLXBheS15YXki)

Comment: I had `q$/-(.)ay/$ w q` for 15 but unfortunately that fails on inputs containing multiple copies of `-<char>ay` (it corrects them all rather than just the last). Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>22</s> 17 bytes

```
ṖṖṙ-Ṗµṣ”-ṪḊ⁼⁾ayµ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmlgNFMXSB3a@nDn4kcNc4HsVQ93dD1q3POocV9i5aGthxb@//8/M123ILFStzKxEgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 22 bytes

```
{S/(.+)\-(.)ay$/$1$0/}
```

Basic regular expression solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 146 bytes

```java
s->{Matcher m=Pattern.compile("(.*)-(.)ay").matcher(s);String g="";while(m.find())g=m.group(1);return (g!=""?s.charAt(s.lastIndexOf('-')+1)+g:s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU/LTsMwELznK5YIqTbFRlwJLeKCxKECqUfEwU0cx8WxLXtdiKp@e3FpeRzJHLyr3Zn1zFpsBHNe2nXztte9dwFhnWc8oTY8SCU/@EUFV1cQO5dMAysJ2tYmNbLJDawGlFC7ZLEofFoZXUNtRIywEHm7LSDjNI8oMJeN0w30eUuWGLRVL68ggor0RD7g10CbbI3aWf5wam6Poks41jm0MIN9ZPPtQmDdyQD97FkgymB57XqvjSQl4ReUEU7FUFLeH3kk0up4A9SsLKv37kDteattQyhVs56r4JIn17QKElOwQNRZZt5FXnci3COJPCfFR9vIj6eWTNiETq/pVN3ky7v9d5bqJ9VyiCh77hJyn/9FY0nLhfdmIKU0xrHu4I/@T9B9Kd5dMM04zb/Z@ZVMjLCkFVviCP5XgowxsY04j0yNM@XFwIY/kl2xK/af)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

I know there already is [a 15-bytes 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128064/52210). <s>I haven't found anything shorter yet, but since I found two 15-byters with a different approach, I figured I'd post them as well</s> EDIT: Found a 14-byter. But I'll still mention the two 15-byters either way:

```
œ6è…-ayÅ¿i¨¨Á¨
```

Very slow for larger inputs.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//8WTNsOo4oCmLWF5w4XCv2nCqMKow4HCqP//aWctU3RheQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn2ly/9gMz1Pr0cNy3QTKw@3HtqfeWjFoRWHGw@t@F@r8z81JydfNyOxkisDzCrPL8pJgbC5CgpyUnUTgVKJIBZXZrpucAmQB1YHBCBNOYkqxbrpQAZQsiCxUrcysRIA). (The test suite uses `S6.IJ` instead of `œ6è`, since it's A LOT faster, but basically does the same. Unfortunately, builtin `.I` doesn't work on strings - apparently.)

```
4(è«…ay-Å¿i¨¨Á¨
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9vc2FiaWX//zQow6jCq@KApmF5LcOFwr9pwqjCqMOBwqj//2lnLVN0YXk) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l4Qn/TTQOrzi0@lHDssRK3cOth/ZnHlpxaMXhxkMr/tfq/E/NycnXzUis5MoAs8rzi3JSIGyugoKcVN1EoFQiiMWVma4bXALkgdUBAUhTTqJKsW46kAGULAAaX5lYCQA).

```
`«ŠŠ«…ay-QiJÁëI
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//2DCq8WgxaDCq@KApmF5LVFpSsOBw6tJ//9pZy1TdGF5) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l/4RDq48uOLrg0OpHDcsSK3UDM70ONx5eXfm/Vkcz5n9qTk6@bkZiJVcGmFWeX5STAmFzFRTkpOomAqUSQSyuzHTd4BIgD6wOCECachJVinXTgQygZAHQ7MrESgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
œ               # Get all permutations of the (implicit) input-string
 6è             # Only leave the 7th one (0-based 6th)
   …-ayÅ¿i      # If this permutation ends with "-ay":
          ¨¨    #  Remove the last two characters from the (implicit) input-string ("ay")
            Á   #  Rotate it once towards the right
             ¨  #  Rotate the last character ("-")
                #  (after which it is output implicitly as result)
                # (implicit else)
                #  (implicitly output the implicit input unchanged)

4(è             # Get the 0-based -4'th character of the (implicit) input
   «            # Append it to the (implicit) input
    …ay-Å¿i     # If this string ends with "ay-"
           ¨¨Á¨ #  Same as above

`               # Push all characters of the (implicit) input separately to the stack
 «              # Merge the last two together
  ŠŠ            # Triple-swap the last three items twice (a,b,c to b,c,a)
    «           # Merge the top two together
     …ay-Qi     # If this is equal to "ay-":
           J    #  Join the other characters on the stack together
            Á   #  And rotate it once towards the right
          ë     # Else:
           I    #  Push the input
                # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 18 bytes

```
a~`-(.)ay$`?$1.$`a
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCJfIC4gXCIgIC0+ICBcIiAuIHsiLCJhfmAtKC4pYXkkYD8kMS4kYGEiLCJ9IE0gW1xuIFwiZWxsby1oYXlcIlxuIFwiaGVsbG8td29ybGRcIlxuIFwiaGVsbG9cIlxuIFwicHBsZS1hYXlcIlxuIFwiYXBwbGVcIlxuIFwiaWctU3RheVwiXG4gXCJlbGxvLS0tLWhheVwiXG4gXCJsYSRzLWdheVwiXG4gXCJpZy1wYXkteWF5XCJcbl0iLCIiLCItbCJd)

#### Explanation

```
a~`-(.)ay$`?$1.$`a
a                   First command-line argument
 ~                  Find first match
  `-(.)ay$`         of this regex (capture the letter in group 1)
           ?        If a match was found:
            $1        Contents of group 1
              .       Concatenated with
               $`     Portion of the string before the match
                    Else:
                 a    The string unchanged
```